# Paypal - use latest API version by default

Tags: paypal

I’d like my app to always use the latest version of the Paypal API, it’s my understanding that if I do not specify “VERSION” in the NVP collection the latest version will be called by default. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's just one of the many lies in the Paypal docs :)

10006 
 Version error 
 Version is not supported

So I'm using "the current version" which as of October 2 2012 is 95.0 ([link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_PreviousAPIVersionsNVP)).

Comment: "No, that's just one of the many lies in the Paypal docs :)" - Not sure where you got that from, but that's not in the docs. VERSION is *always* a required parameter. The latest version is 86.0.

Comment: Where can I find the latest version number?

Comment: Link to "what's new in version x" :
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_PreviousAPIVersionsNVP
I suppose they update this when there's a new API version.

Comment: Here's the api version history : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/#MerchantAPI

Comment: @Robert https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_PreviousVersionsNVP/ "Unless specifically specified, API operations default to the latest version."

Comment: Well spotted. At the time of my answer that doc didn't exist yet! ;-)
But I'm afraid it's incorrect. I'll ask them to fix that doc.