# PayPal is returning Version not supported no matter what

Tags: paypal

I know that this [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661664/paypal-use-latest-api-version-by-default).

I'm using [PayPal Recurring](https://github.com/fredxinfan/paypal-recurring).

The documentation of paypal itself is so far from what is an acceptable degree of readabillity and usabillity that I may have missed an essential point.

But I used the VERSION [of the module](https://github.com/fredxinfan/paypal-recurring/blob/master/lib/paypal/recurring.rb#L115), the version used in the [docs example](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/) and the [current version](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_Release_Notes_109/). I've tried without version. I even tried to [ucfirst the version](http://www.ecwid.com/forums/showthread.php?p=72016), but PayPal always reports "Version is not supported". I do not even understand why I have to give the version.

How can I debug that?

If the day will once arise, where it works, will I have to worry that my app suddenly crashes because the version number changes?

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't understand and I don't want to understand, adding `config.ssl_cert = false` to my sandbox account settings in `paypal-recurring` (or `ssl_cert` from the final request) solved the problem.